# HTML/JS modal load

Tags: javascript, html, css

My problem is that I can't automatically show my modal.

In the best case, I need a timer that opens the modal (for example, 10 seconds after the page loads).

https://codepen.io/martin-len/pen/ExjJayx

```
<script>

// Working metods to open modal with button.
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";


}

// And here im trying open modal automaticaly. All methods dont work.

// method 1
$(document).ready(function(){
modal.style.display = "block";
});

// method 2
window.onload = function(){ 
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

$(document).ready(function(){
$("#myModal").modal('show');
});

</script>
```

Comment: By a modal are you meaning like a large popup box?

Answer (score 0):

Here is working: https://codepen.io/ealipio/pen/mdJgyYK

```
window.onload = function(e){   
  var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
  var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

  modal.style.display = "block";
}
```

the issue is that you have to use those methods when the entire page was loaded. that happens inside window.onload event.

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

I would say Eisson's answer is technically correct. It is worth informing as to WHY this is happening to you.

Look here.

```
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

window.onload = function(){ 
    modal.style.display = "block";
}
```

Notice the variable **modal**. It is being defined in whatever scope you have it in.

Now, **notice how window.onload is another function**. This is breaking the scope and availability of the modal variable.

**You can use Eisson's answer, however. That would REMOVE modal from the previous scope rendering not accessible outside of the onload function.**

So what you can do is change your above provided code to

```
window.onload = () => { 
    modal.style.display = "block";
}
```

There are some technical difference between functions and arrow functions that you can read about on this resource. Both Eisson's and my own answer will work. My answer leaves modal in the scope that you have indicated and minimally changes the boilerplate you have provided.

[Arrow Functions vs Functions](https://medium.com/better-programming/difference-between-regular-functions-and-arrow-functions-f65639aba256)